# Powershell to format other command's outputs

Tags: powershell, formatting

Is there a way to use powershell to format the output of non-powershell commands in tabular form.

I am retrieving the cluster resources' status remotely using "Cluster  resource" and I can't load the Powershell cluster module on this server.

[image]

Comment: `cluster.exe` is deprecated. Use the proper [PowerShell cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619751%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for cluster management.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - You can should be able to run the executable in PowerShell, and send the command's output to the pipeline, working with it like any other object.  `.\poorlyformatted.exe | % {$_ | .. do some formatting per line...}`

If the output from a command doesn't use stdout you'll have trouble.

Comment: `cluster <servername> resource| % {$_ | Format-Table -Wrap`

This just added a blank row between rows.But nowhere near the proper table format. Tried `wrap`, `autosize`, `format-list`. Didn't help.

Then used 
`cluster <servername> resource| % {$_ | Format-Wide -columns 1}`

to just get the resource names. It still loads the entire table.
@ChrisN How do I confirm if the legacy `cluster` command uses stdout ...

Comment: You're only returning one object to the pipeline right now - a line of text..  You need to parse the text in some way to build relevant objects... maybe split the string on whatever the special character for a tab is, and then assign each piece of the resulting array to a property using New-Object.